# Line cannot display over area in XY Area Line Chart of Pentaho

Tags: pentaho

I have created one area line chart by using Pentaho Report Designer.
But the line is hiding under area.
Please refer to the attached figure.

[image]

How can I change the settings to display line on area???

Comment: There is no figure attached. Didn't you have the privilege to do this?

Comment: sorry, I tried to attached the image but I have no permission to import image yet.. could you please refer http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-5093 ???

Comment: Thank you all for your attention. Now, I can see line on area. I have answered how to do in http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?163359-Pentaho-XY-Area-Line-Chat-cannot-display-line-on-area&p=376063#post376063

Comment: Consider answering your own question to formally close it. This way you gain reputation on SO and you help others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you write the code in Chart Post-Processing Script, you will see the line on area.

```
import org.jfree.chart.JFreeChart;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.CategoryPlot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.DatasetRenderingOrder;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.Plot;
import org.jfree.chart.plot.XYPlot;


Plot plot = chart.getPlot();
if (plot instanceof CategoryPlot) {
((CategoryPlot) plot).setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
} else if (plot instanceof XYPlot) {
((XYPlot) plot).setDatasetRenderingOrder(DatasetRenderingOrder.FORWARD);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for your attention. Now, I can see line on area. I have answered how to do in http://forums.pentaho.com/showthread.php?163359-Pentaho-XY-Area-Line-Chat-cannot-display-line-on-area&p=375561#post375561 and http://jira.pentaho.com/browse/PRD-5093

Comment: Please, take the time to copy the most important steps over from the referred site. The idea is that questions and answers on Stack Exchange should be self-contained even if the referred sites go out-of-service or the URL's change.